# How to use quotename for varchar(max) field?

Tags: sql-server

select QUOTENAME (col1) from table1

Shows null,but table having value ,Col1 data type is varchar(2000)

Answer (score 2):

QUOTENAME takes as parameter SYSNAME, which is equivalent to NVARCHAR(128). The following statement does the same as QUOTENAME (without parameters), for any (N)VARCHAR field:

```
select '['+REPLACE(col1,']',']]')+']' from table1
```

---

As in your comments it appears you don't know the column type beforehand. Casting to VARCHAR(MAX) first could work:

```
select '['+REPLACE(CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)),']',']]')+']' from table1
```

Comment: Perhaps Concat is more readable. SELECT CONCAT('[',col1,']') from table1

Comment: Thanks ,but i have problem in this sp_generate_inserts SP. while form @QUOTED_DATA variable dont know about column data type, so concat or merge a string is not possible..

Comment: Please add more information. In your title you mentioned a varchar field and now you don't know the type of the column ....

Comment: The CONCAT suggestion alone, without replace does not the job and will fail preventing injection for a value like 

`'col1]; SELECT * FROM sys.tables; SELECT [col1'` @TT. 's answer is correct and should be marked as such.

Comment: @Tjasun CONCAT is ok to use, if it is supported by your version of SQL Server (i.e. 2012+). The statement you have in comment, would need to have the REPLACE ] -> ]] though.